# Why is UIKeyboardDidShowNotification/UIKeyboardWillHideNotification fired when coming back from modal view?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I have implemented a scrolling feature, where the textfield is not hidden from the keyboard. Therefore I'm working with `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, where the scrolling takes place. For the scrolling I need to know the current active textfield. This is done with `EditingDidBegin` and `EditingDidEnd`.

The code is in C# but there is no much difference:

```
usernameText.EditingDidBegin += delegate {
    activeTextField = usernameText;
};
usernameText.EditingDidEnd += delegate {
    activeTextField = null;
};
```

The flow of my application looks like the following:

1. User starts application and one textfield is becoming the first responder. The keyboard pops up and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is correctly called.
2. User presses another button and another view is presented modally.
3. `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` is called correctly as well as my active textfield is cleared out in `EditingDidEnd`.
4. When coming back from my modal view `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` are called again despite there is no keyboard active.

In `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` I need the active text field which is null at that time and my app crashes. Now I used a null check for that so that the app doesn't crash.

But why are the two notifications are sent again when there is no need to?

Comment: in step 2: "User presses another button and another view is presented modally." before presenting a viewController hide Your keyboard.

Comment: You are right. Dismissing the keyboard before modally presenting the view solves the problem. You can post your comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in step 2: "User presses another button and another view is presented modally." before presenting a viewController hide Your keyboard